# Binary shift of int not possible

Tags: c++, bit-shift

```
usigned int val = 1;
val <<= 30; 
cout << intToBin(val) << endl;

string intToBin(unsigned int val) {
    unsigned int k=1;
    string ret;
    while (k <= val) {
        if (k & val) {
            ret.insert(0,"1");
        } else {
            ret.insert(0,"0");
        }
        k <<= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This will write 1 and 30x 0 which is alright. But what I need is to have the 1 on the highest bit, meaning on the first position - followed by 31x zeros. But when I try to val <<= 31; nothing is written, which I don't understand. Could you clarify that for me please?

Thank you

Comment: Nothing being written means, that the first k is evaluated greater than val. So either you're not using unsigned properly, your architecture is only 31 bits wide or you encountered a compiler bug. It's BTW a rather strange way to emit a binary representation, I'd just start with the highest bit, and emit characters on the first non-zero bit. Those front insertions have far more cost, than testing those worst case n-1 bits up front (except if you're working with really long numbers). Largest C word size I know about being in use by current architectures: long long with 128 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your while loop will not terminate if `val` is `>= 2^31`.

This is because `k == 2^31` is still `<=` `val` but `2^31 << 1 == 2^32` overflows and becomes 0. Which is still smaller than the limit.

You could extend your condition to break if `k == 0` too, then the problem should disappear.

(`^` means exponentiation not xor in this post)